# Trouble with libc6 in Debian

Tags: debian-installer

I have a Debian i386 system, recently updated to 9.8 stretch. I need to install libc6_2.28 for an application, but the system doesn't. If I run

```
sudo apt-get -f install libc6
```

the result is: 2.24-11+deb9u4

even though when I check the version

`cat /etc/debian_version`

the answer is 9.8.

Answer (score 2):

Debian 9.x "stretch" uses version 2.24 of `libc6`. The current version is 2.24-11+deb9u4, i.e. it includes a lot of patches and backported security bugfixes compared to upstream version 2.24. The `deb9u4` part indicates this packaged version may have some dependencies requiring the system as a whole to be at Debian 9.4 or above.

**Warning:** `libc6` is a pretty fundamental package that is used by essentially all system binaries. Debian `buster` (i.e. the current `testing`) has version 2.28 of `libc6`, but [you should not install it to `stretch`.](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

> ### Don't make a FrankenDebian
>
> Debian Stable should not be combined with other releases. If you're trying to install software that isn't available in the current Debian Stable release, it's not a good idea to add repositories for other Debian releases. The problems might not happen right away, but the next time you install updates.
>
> The reason things can break is because the software packaged for one Debian release is built to be compatible with the rest of the software for that release. For example, installing packages from buster on a stretch system could also install newer versions of core libraries including libc6. This results in a system that is not testing or stable but a broken mix of the two.

What you are trying to do is exactly "installing a newer version of core library libc6". This is known to break things. Don't do it (unless you're updating the entire system to `buster` of course).

If an application requires `libc6` version 2.28 or higher, then **it is not compatible with Debian 9.**